# Should I unsubscribe from an Observable derived from a Subject?

Tags: angular, rxjs

If I subscribe to a Subject, then I have to unsubscribe. If I subscribe to an Observable, then I may skip unsubscription step, because it's done automatically as far as I know.

What about the next case.

```
export class PlacesService {
  private _places = new BehaviorSubject<Place[]>([
    new Place(
      'p1',
      'Manhattan Mansion',
      'In the heart of New York City',
      'http://www.boweryboyshistory.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/top1.jpg',
      149.9,
      new Date('2019-01-01'),
      new Date('2019-12-31'),
      'dima')]);
  get places() {
    return this._places.asObservable();
  }
}

export class DiscoverPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  loadedPlaces: Place[];
  placesSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private placeService: PlacesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('DiscoverPage: ngOnInit');
    this.placesSubscription = this.placeService.places.subscribe(places => this.loadedPlaces = places);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('ngOnDestroy');
    this.placesSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

May I remove `placesSubscription` and expect to be automatically unsubscribed as the object I subscribe to is of type `Observable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unsubscribe it.

Angular does not automatically unsubscribe the observables that you created by yourself.

Comment: Unless you are using the async pipe. Then Angular does handles the subscription within its life cycle.

Answer (score 2):

When you have an infinite sequence, you should unsubscribe (unless you have a special case), for example when using the interval() or the fromEvent() observables.

**Don’t Unsubscribe:**

**Async pipe**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `<todos [todos]="todos$ | async"></todos>`
})
export class TestComponent {    
  constructor(private store: Store) { }    
  ngOnInit() {
     this.todos$ = this.store.select('todos');
  }    
}
```

**@HostListener**

```
export class TestDirective {    
  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    ....
  }      
}
```

**Finite Observable**

```
export class TestComponent {   
  constructor(private http: Http) { }    
  ngOnInit() {
    Observable.timer(1000).subscribe(console.log);
    this.http.get('http://api.com').subscribe(console.log);
  }      
}
```

More info:

https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3